# Java - Load html page from assets

Tags: java

I'm trying to load a html page located in my assets folder.

I'm able to load an online html webpage (eg: http://google.com) with this code

```
    ...
    dtrpnHey = new JEditorPane();
    dtrpnHey.setEditable(false);
    try {
          dtrpnHey.setPage("http://google.com");
        }catch (IOException e) {
            dtrpnHey.setContentType("text/html");
            dtrpnHey.setText("<html>Could not load</html>");
        } 

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(dtrpnHey);     
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test HTML");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        f.setVisible(true);
    panel_1.add(dtrpnHey);
            ...
```

I know `file:///android_asset/mynicehtmlfile.html` works on android, but since it contains `android_assets` I think it won't on non-android.

Thank you very much!

EDIT: Assuming that I can have a folder inside my jar file (inside my project folder) that's called: assets (http://s24.postimg.org/p02ju9xip/Knipsel.jpg?noCache=1370175365)

Comment: What is your assets folder? A folder on the file system? A directory in the jar of your application?

Comment: It's a folder/directory that I have inside my jar file (http://s24.postimg.org/p02ju9xip/Knipsel.jpg?noCache=1370175365)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
editorPane.setPage(SomeClass.class.getResource("/assets/thePage.html"));
```

should do it if the assets folder really is in the jar. From the image you posted, it isn't, since assets is not inside any source folder of your project. Eclipse's runtime classpath is composed from all the jars in the build path of the project, and from the target directory where it puts the compiled classes and all the resources which are in the source directory. If you don't put the assets folder in the source directory, Eclipse won't make it part of the runtime classpath.